# wynk OR Gaana music not playing on webview android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-music-player

I want to play a music from any music app(gaana/wynk/saavn etc) using webview android. My requirement is I want to open a music app in webview and user can play music directly using webview just like we open (gaaan/wynk/saavn) in web browser of mobile device and you can play any song.

I tried gaana and wynk music, both are able to open on webview but when i am clicking on any songs that songs does not play. do i need to enable any settings for that i already have enabled javascript.

below is the code i have tried.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{
   @Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
   {
   }
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
   {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
   }
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   }
});
```

Please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Enable `Javascript` in your WebView `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: I already have enabled it.

Comment: open the same link on browser on phone. Are you able to play audio? Also share logs for warning and errors on webview

Comment: open the same link on browser on phone. Are you able to play audio? Also share logs for warning and errors on webview

Comment: yes it works if I use the same link on browser. In Web view if you use "https" then songs does not play but if you use "http" then songs play. For the time being I have used "http". If anyone find solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

its because app cant use storage.

```
  WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
  webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This solves the problem !